# unload R package's compiled code to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: r, memory-leaks, package, r-package

I have a large C program (can't share reproducible code) that I'd like to include within R package so that users don't have to compile it themselves and it's self-contained. So the compiled code part is used only by only one package function, something like

```
wrapperfoo <- function(config_file_path, output_file_path) {
  #stuff
  #...
  .C("myprogram", config_file_path, output_file_path)
  #... 
}
```

The problem with C code is that it uses Flex/Bison scanner/parser which doesn't reset. Code is not mine and I want to avoid rewriting the scanner (and simple fixes in C didn't work, including some topics on SO suggesting e.g. `yylex_destroy()`, I'm a C newbie so debugging is difficult).

It's completely fine if in R I unload the package after calling on my program and load it again. (And it works fine if compiled & run outside of R.)

So this works:

```
library(mypackage)
wrapperfunction()
unloadNamespace("mypackage") #invokes library.dynam.unload()
library(mypackage)
wrapperfunction()
```

But this won't:

```
library(mypackage)
wrapperfunction()
wrapperfunction() #parser crashes and with it R
```

Is it OK to load and unload DLL within my `wrapperfunction()`? Seems to me that it's against good practices for R package writing and I don't even know if it's possible? 
Or is there another function that would clean-up after .C? Would using .Call help? `gc()` doesn't help

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? What did you try in C? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47359142/8416610 for a very simple approach.

Comment: I think I've tried all simple examples around lexer, including `yylex_destroy()`, no good.

Comment: And no chance to write a complete example as the bug is specific to code I can't share. But I think my question is more theoretical: is it possible/allowed to load and unload dynamic library within package? Or is there another solution that simulates this behaviour?

Comment: In that case the r-pkg-devel mailing list might be the better place for the question: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Ralf, will try there too

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `?unloadNamespace` and if your C code is compiled into a shared library also `?library.dynam.unload` which should be called in your package's `.onUnload` function like this: `gc(); library.dynam.unload("yourSharedLibraryName", libpath)`